# Shell quotes with IFS in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: bash, jenkins, backslash, quote, ifs

I'm trying to set IFS in a Bash shell within a Jenkins pipeline script.  See line 34 below.  The problem is I can't get the multi-level quoting correct.  If I'm just typing at a bash terminal, the line would be `IFS=$'\n'`.  But, no matter how many backslashes I use in different combinations, I can't make it work.  At this point, I'm just guessing.

The `$filename` variable at the end of line 36 is a list of file names that have internal spaces separated by linefeed characters (`\n`).  Hence, I want the IFS variable to be only `\n`.

[image]

Here is the same snippet in text form.

```
steps {
    sh """
        #!/bin/bash
        export PATH="$PATH:/root/.local/bin"
        IFS=\$\\'\\n\\'
        pip install -r requirements.txt --user
        python EC_Workload_Analysis/combine.py --webdav --zipfile ${BUILD_NUMBER} --user $SCRIPT_CREDS_USR --password $SCRIPT_CREDS_PSW $filenames
       """
      }
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend putting that code in a script. Trying to maintain non-trivial code written within another language is always a massive pain.

Comment: `IFS=$'\n'` works on my redhat but not on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try with

```
export IFS=$(echo -e "\n ")
```

because you can't insert the character you need, but you can create and store it, to test this you can do

```
echo "$IFS $IFS $IFS"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to l0b0 for the comment!  I put lines 32 to 36 in their own script in my git repo, `run_me.sh`, removed the extraneous quotes and backslashes, and then put `bash < run_me.sh` in place of lines 32 to 36.

`run_me.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH="$PATH:/root/.local/bin"
export IFS=$'\n'
pip install -r requirements.txt --user
python EC_Workload_Analysis/combine.py --webdav --zipfile $BUILD_NUMBER --user $SCRIPT_CREDS_USR --password $SCRIPT_CREDS_PSW $filenames
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like below code snippet and try.

```
steps {
    sh """
        #!/bin/bash
        export PATH="$PATH:/root/.local/bin"
        IFS=\$'\\n'
        pip install -r requirements.txt --user
        python EC_Workload_Analysis/combine.py --webdav --zipfile ${BUILD_NUMBER} --user $SCRIPT_CREDS_USR --password $SCRIPT_CREDS_PSW $filenames
       """
      }
```

**Explanation:**
In double qoutes, `$` is treated as a special character and so it needs to be escaped using `\`. `\` is also a special character so we will escape that too by replacing it with double slashes `\\`.

I have tried with dummy data so please confirm if it works with your requirement or not.